# Getting the ID of a resource in a nested URL Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested, parameters, nested-routes

What I'm looking to do is set the "album_id" attribute of my Song instance equal to the ID of the album currently being viewed.

For example:

http://localhost:3000/artist_profiles/1/albums/2

In the above URL, I would like to set the "album_id" of the song I am creating equal to 2.

My songs_controller:

```
class Albums::SongsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_user_friendships

  def new
  end

  def create
    # Make an object in your bucket for your song
    obj = S3_BUCKET.objects[params[:file].original_filename]

    # Upload the file
    obj.write(
      file: params[:file],
      acl: :public_read
    )

    # Create an object for the song
    @song = Song.new(
        url: obj.public_url,
        name: obj.key
        )

    @song.album_id = Album.find(params[:id])

    # Save the upload
    if @song.save
      redirect_to artist_profile_albums_path(current_user.id), success: 'File successfully uploaded'
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = 'There was an error'
      render :new
    end
  end

  def index
    @user_friendships = current_user.user_friendships.all
    @songs = Song.all
  end

  def song_params
    params.require(:song).permit(:id, :url, :name, :song_title, :album_id)
  end

  def set_user_friendships
    @user_friendships = current_user.user_friendships.all #this is here because of partial UGHHH
  end

end
```

More specifically, the following line:

```
@song.album_id = Album.find(params[:id])
```

However, when I try this code I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find Album with 'id'=
```

If I try:

```
@song.album_id = Album.find(2).id
```

or:

```
@song.album_id = 2
```

I get 0 errors.

The route I am looking at after running the rake routes command is:

```
/artist_profiles/:artist_profile_id/albums/:id(.:format)
```

How would I go about getting the ID of the proper album?

Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE:

My log when attempting to upload the song:

```
Started POST "/songs" for ::1 at 2016-07-04 07:34:32 -0400
Processing by Albums::SongsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/pZp493WqiDgkJC72ueK5Wr4eVqdVvWzY43c/ru/OpSt3J9gECwC7nIhszLgyef218sRWsAr9xSZOnH751MUoA==", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff871c261b0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/xb/38dybzwn51g3fg4vb7kdgg5m0000gn/T/RackMultipart20160704-11159-5aarh7.mp3>, @original_filename="03 Exit Wounds (Original Mix).mp3", @content_type="audio/mp3", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"03 Exit Wounds (Original Mix).mp3\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/mp3\r\n">, "commit"=>"Upload song"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
[AWS S3 200 16.701785 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"atmosphere-development",:content_length=>13561000,:data=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff871c261b0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/xb/38dybzwn51g3fg4vb7kdgg5m0000gn/T/RackMultipart20160704-11159-5aarh7.mp3>, @original_filename="03 Exit Wounds (Original Mix).mp3", @content_type="audio/mp3", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"03 Exit Wounds (Original Mix).mp3\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/mp3\r\n">,:key=>"03 Exit Wounds (Original Mix).mp3")  

  Album Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "albums".* FROM "albums" WHERE "albums"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 16748ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Album with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/albums/songs_controller.rb:24:in `create'


  Rendered /Users/sethjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (5.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/sethjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/sethjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/sethjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (60.4ms)
Cannot render console with content type multipart/form-dataAllowed content types: [#<Mime::Type:0x007ff8731e25a8 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html">, #<Mime::Type:0x007ff8731e22d8 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:text, @string="text/plain">, #<Mime::Type:0x007ff8731dae20 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:url_encoded_form, @string="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">]
```

Comment: can you share route and log?

Comment: Actually need to check which id do you get in params[:id], is it album id or song id?

Comment: How would I go about checking that? Rails is telling me that the ID doesn't exist.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/artist_profiles/1/albums/2  when you are on this page you can see params in log and then error right? so can paste here that so can trace something from that

Comment: i think you are not passing album id in following line like eg. artist_profile_albums_path(current_user.id, :album_id => 2)

Comment: I updated the question so that it includes my log when uploading the song. Thanks for your time!

Comment: i think i got it, you need to send some id like better it would "album_id" from your form, then @song.album_id = Album.find(params[:album_id]) will work, currently create action doesn't getting any id.

Comment: When changing the line to @song.album_id = Album.find(params[:album_id]) I get the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116368/discussion-between-chaitanya-and-user3700231).

Answer (score 3):

After the discussions in the chat:

```
params[:album_id].to_i worked.
```

Apparently rails didn't convert the id to integer when he tried to assign it like this:

```
@song.album_id = params[:album_id]
```

--

Anyway the way i do it is by creating the nested model through its parent model.

So instead of writing this code:

```
@song = Song.new(
    url: obj.public_url,
    name: obj.key
    )

@song.album_id = Album.find(params[:id])
```

you can write:

```
album = Album.find(params[:id])
@song = album.songs.build(url: obj.public_url, name: obj.key)
```

and it should set the album_id to the correct one. (which is the id of `album` that we get from the query).

But this way you have an extra query to find the album, and with the `.to_i` method you don't, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved thanks to @chaitanya and @Ziv Galili

Changed the line to:

```
@song.album_id = params[:album_id].to_i
```

And added album_id to the upload form.